# Why is a bottom-aligned component extending outside the size of <body>?

Tags: html, css

I am placing elements aligned to the top and bottom of `body`, which has its size set explicitly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                height: 1024px;
                width: 1280px;
                font-size: 20pt;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                justify-content: flex-start;
            }
            div {
                background: red;
                color: white;
            }
            .down {
                margin-top: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="up">upper text</div>
        <div class="down">lower text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The bottom element, however, extends outside of the preset size (I attach two screenshots because I could not have at the same time the Chrome dev tools displaying the computed size and the ruler app showing its length - this is the same window):

[image] [image]

**Why is it so?** Shouldn't all the components of the `div` (content, padding, border) be taken into account when calculating the position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the default `margin` from the body:

```
      body {
        height: 1024px;
        width: 1280px;
        font-size: 20pt;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 0;
      }
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that there was a margin by default. I though that, if not set, it would be calculated automatically (and therefore that there would be none for `body`).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried resetting the default values of the body?

if not, you may try this

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```